# Banner appearing on Pages but not Posts; call it conditional confusion

Tags: posts, conditional-content, header-image

I have a banner image that appears on Pages that I want. However, I also have a Page designated as a Blog where it doesn't appear. Is there any way to have this banner appear on a Page that is using a blog template? Tried messing around with adding `is_home()` or `is_page( $id )` to code below but I'm grasping at straws, appreciate your thoughts

```
//* Add Header Images on Posts/Pages
add_image_size( 'header-img', 1600);
add_action('after_header', 'site_banner', 0);
function site_banner(){
    if( !is_singular( 'page' ) )
        return;

    if( has_post_thumbnail() && is_page() ) :
        $ftbanner = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'header-img' );
        $banner = $ftbanner[0];
        echo '<div id="site-banner" class="site-banner">' . "\n";
        echo '<img src="' . $banner . '">' . "\n";
        echo '</div>' . "\n";
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the attention to detail @Howdy_McGee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've designated a specific page to be your Post Archive ( blog ) it no longer is a standard page; meaning `is_page()` will likely fail. Since your blog page is now more of an archive, it is automatically being returned because of your first conditional.

- [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) - Returns `true` when viewing a single page, post, or post type.

So what you're saying is **IF** we're **NOT** viewing a **Singular Page** then return. Since blog is no longer a singular page, instead, let's say:

```
if( ! is_page() && ! is_home() )
    return;
```

Next, since this blog page is an archive now we cannot reply on the `global $post` to give us the correct ID for the blog page, thus `get_the_ID()` will fail. What we need to do is get the blog ID using the following:

```
$blog_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

I've taken some liberties below with your function but it should work the same.

```
//* Add Header Images on Posts/Pages
add_image_size( 'header-img', 1600 );
add_action( 'after_header', 'site_banner', 0 );
function site_banner() {
    if( ( is_page() || is_home() ) ) {
        $post_id = ( is_home() ? get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) : get_the_ID() );

        if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
            $ftbanner = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'header-img' );
            $banner = $ftbanner[0];
            echo '<div id="site-banner" class="site-banner">' . "\n";
            echo '<img src="' . $banner . '">' . "\n";
            echo '</div>' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing differently here is right off the bat I make sure we are either viewing a page or the blog page and if we are, set the `$post_id` then verify that that page has a featured image set. IF it does have one set, show the banner image.

Comment: I'm kind of blown away right now, thank you @howdy_mcgee you nailed it! Especially appreciate how skillfully you explained and dissected this. I love PHP but I'm also completely humbled by it at times like this. Really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: @Chris Thanks! If you found this helpful, don't forget to upvote / mark as answered ( checkmark ) so that future viewers know your question was addressed, and welcome to the WordPress community!

Comment: Hey @Howdy_McGee I just realized that my pages have the banner, but my posts themselves don't, is this correct: `if( ( is_page() || is_home() || is_single() )  ) {`

Comment: @Chris that looks right, if you have other post types you could also check `is_singular( 'post' );` which would only return true if viewing a single post of post-type `post` ( which is a tad confusing I know ).